# Why is Collections.frequency returning zero for my collection?

Tags: java, arraylist

May someone explain to me what I am doing wrong in order to add these items to my inventory arraylist? The problem is when I go to check the inventory of a certain item with [`Collections.frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) it continues to say that there is zero of that item.

```
private List<Food> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
private double balance = 100.00;

public void startingInv(){
    addFoods(10, Food.HAMBURGER);
    addFoods(10, Food.CHEESEBURGER);
    addFoods(10, Food.HOTDOG);
    addFoods(10, Food.SODA);
    addFoods(10, Food.CHEESIEBOY);
    addFoods(10, Food.WATER);
    addFoods(10, Food.YEET);
}
```

Above is the method where I am attempting to add the different types of food to the inventory arraylist (which I have called to my Food.java class).

Below is the addFoods method which is being called each time for each food in the above code.

```
    public int addFoods(int amount, int type){
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        this.inventory.add(new Food(type));
    }
    return Collections.frequency(inventory, type);
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is!

Comment: Whenever I go to check the inventory, it says that there are zero of every item.

Comment: `inventory` contains elements of type `Food` not `Integer`, that's why `Collections.frequency` is returning `0`

Comment: You'll also need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` on `Food`.

Answer (score 1):

Be mindful of [what the API is actually doing here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-).

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e in the collection such that `Objects.equals(o, e)`.

The way to fix this:

- Implement `equals` for your `Food` class
- Instantiate an instance of `Food` which contains the specific type you want
- Use `Collections.frequency(inventory, instanceOfFoodYouCareAbout)`

Comment: I'm guessing that I did not explain it well. In my other class each food has an integer amount to avoid this problem. For example I stated that Hamburger is equal to 1, so I could avoid this. However, it still will not cooperate despite the Foods being integers.

Comment: Well no...you have `Food` and not anything else in that collection.  The type of object you're dealing with is and will remain `Food` from the perspective of that collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is always returning `0` because `inventory` contains elements of type `Food` not `Integer`, so essentially you're attempting to compare `Integer` objects with `Food` objects by doing `Collections.frequency(inventory, type);` and therefore `Objects.equals(o, e)` would never be `true` for these two different types.

You can either implement `equals`/`hashcode` as mentioned by Makoto or as 
an alternative to returning the frequency of a given element in `inventory` without implementing `equals`/`hashcode` would be:

```
return (int)inventory.stream()
                     .filter(f -> f.getType() == type)
                     .count();
```

where `getType` is a getter returning the value of `type` in any given `Food` instance. In other words, you must have a getter called `getType` in your `Food` class returning the value of `type`.

Comment: I am a student so may you please explain what you mean by implementing the equals type? would i do something like Food.equals() or am I incorrect?